# WSO2 api manager always expect query parameter issue in case query and path parameter?

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Does anyone know how to use WSO2 api manager to specify all query parameters as optional through URL pattern specification in WSO2 API Manager UI(Paath Params also present in the same URI)? for example, I have a API which will be registered in WSO2 api manager , and its uri is 'search//?type="xx"&status="yy"', currently both of these 2 query parameters (type & status) are optional and  is pathparam.

I specified URL Pattern "search/{stationcode}*". Now I am calling with path param only, it gives Error "No matching resource found in the API for the given request".

I call "search/TAMK", it is not working. But if I use "search/TAMK?" or "search/TAMK*" or "search/TAMK*", it works just fine.

I tried to use "search/{stationcode}/*", but still it did not solve the issue. It is always expecting one character for queryparam. Can any one please help me to solve this. Without query parameter it should work, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the new API Manager (1.9) and try the following.
Create an API with the backend URL of
http://...../search

when you define the URL patterns you can define the following pattern

```
/{stationcode}*
```

and you can add 'type' and 'status' as optional parameters in the design view of the API creation page. You can choose the parameter type as 'query' and Required as 'False'

Comment: Thanks, I was trying with API Manager(1.8). I will try in API Manager(1.9) and let you know. Do you know the jira link for this fix in wso2oxygentank so that I can also see that?

Comment: I dont think this is a fix, the same should work in API Manager 1.8. Anyways I would suggest you to try with API Manager 1.9 which supports the latest swagger version.

Comment: It worked for API manager 1.9. It is not working for me using API Manager 1.8. Anyway, I will use API Manger 1.9. Really thanks a lot to you.

Comment: Your welcome. Please use the latest version as it has more features compared to 1.8